# FileSystemWatcher doesn't trigger from SFTP

Tags: c#, .net

I have a C# FileSystemWatcher that is watching for files within a sub-folder that get dropped there.  In our development environment, where we use FTP, the .Created event triggers fine whenever a file is uploaded.  In our production environment, where we use SFTP, the .Created event never fires.  If I move files around using Windows Explorer in either environment, the trigger works fine.  What is the problem?

```
try
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(_watchFolder);
    _watcher = new FileSystemWatcher
    {
        Path = _watchFolder,
        Filter = _watchFilter,
        IncludeSubdirectories = true,
        NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.Size
    };

    _watcher.Created += FileCreated;
    _watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    _logger.Error(ex);
}
```

Comment: Listen to all events or use Process Monitor to see how files are actually created. Likely there are moves instead of creates.

Comment: added an event for _watcher.Changed and NotifyFilters.LastAccess and it works now.